# linq extension methods, how to update multiple properties of a single item?

Tags: linq, ado.net, sql-update, linq-extensions

In my database, I have a single item that I want to update. I tried doing something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
db.Items.Where(t => t.Id == itemId).Select(t =>
            {
                t.CurrentValue = 99;
                t.TotalValue = 999;
            });
```

What works is this code, but I think that this is inefficient (am I wrong?):

```
db.Items.Single(t => t.Id == itemId).TotalValue = 999;
db.Items.Single(t => t.Id == itemId).CurrentValue = 99;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Is there a way to update different properties of a single object, with a single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, running `db.Items.Single(...)` multiple times may be suboptimal.

Calling it once and then referencing its properties should be more efficient:

```
var item = db.Items.Single(t => t.Id == itemId);
item.TotalValue = 999;
item.CurrentValue = 99;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Oh. This works perfectly. Thank you. Now i wonder, how does it know how to connect item object with db object? I didn't specify it anywhere.